# Saving Image As Larger Resolution WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas

What I am trying to do is save an image at a larger resolution, so its big enough to be used for something such as printing on A3 sized paper,

The original image I use from resources is 2344 x 2383 pixels (164kb),
The image once placed on a canvas is 555 x 555,

I was wondering is there a way to save this image from the canvas, but at a larger size, I need it to closer to the original image size,

Here is my current code,

**BUTTON CLICK EVENT**

```
 public static class ImageCapturer
 {
     public static void SaveToBmp(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
     {
         var bitmapEncoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
         SaveUsingEncoder(visual, fileName, bitmapEncoder);
     }

     public static void SaveToPng(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
     {
         var pngBitmapEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
         SaveUsingEncoder(visual, fileName, pngBitmapEncoder);
     }

     private static void SaveUsingEncoder(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
     {
         var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)visual.ActualWidth, (int)visual.ActualHeight, 92, 92, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
         renderTargetBitmap.Render(visual);

         var crop = new CroppedBitmap(renderTargetBitmap, new Int32Rect(575, 60, 555, 550));


         var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap);
         encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(crop));

         using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
         {
             encoder.Save(fileStream);
         }
     }
 }
```

If someone could please give me some advice it would be greatly appreciated,
This has been doing my head in for ages,

If I change the DPI, the Image does become larger, but I only get a a corner of the original image,

Please view these pictures for reference,

Image as it currently is:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/58k5nm1lozp2r0c/BSM_Power_Wheel.png?dl=0
But its too small @ 555 x 555

Image after changing dpi from 92 to 150:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgkwwd0scs9giz8/BSM_Power_Wheeldgdd.png?dl=0

Thank you :)

Comment: See TransformedBitmap (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.transformedbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) and ScaleTransform (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's not really clear to me exactly what you want to do. Once you have reduced the resolution of the bitmap for screen display, resizing it to be larger isn't going to help. It will still be low-resolution. If you want to be able to print the bitmap at or near the original resolution, the best thing is to just keep a copy of the original object, or to reload it for the purpose of printing.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Hi , thanks for the reply..Sorry for the delay getting back to you, I have been out of town, Here is a link of the UI,maybe it will give you a better idea,

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n3ov9zyj6yywuaw/canvas.png?dl=0

So on the right is the image, its in a 555 x 555 pixel container, and you can see the words on the left saying "Default", they will be different phrases,

I would like to drag them onto the circle, and then save the image in a high enough resolution to print it on up to A3 paper,

Does this help you understand my situation?

Comment: What I understand is that you have a bitmap, displayed as a 555x555 image, and which you want to print as an image at a higher resolution. As I said, you can't take an image that is 555x555 and in any meaningful way increase its resolution. You can scale it up, but it won't wind up with any more information than the 555x555 image had. You need to print the original image if you want to print a higher resolution image.

Comment: Thats right @PeterDuniho
The original Image is around 1500 x 1500,
But obviously it would not be suitable to display the image that size on the screen,

Could you please suggest a way that I could go about this?
I would like to take the original 1500 x 1500 wheel, then drag some new images onto it, then save the file again, at near enough the same size as its original? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "drag some new images onto it". If you are talking about a UI like Photoshop where you can layer (composite) images on top of each other, you can. But to maintain resolution, you will need to print using the original images. You can still resize the images for on-screen display, but for printing you'll use the layout the user's specified via the UI, but use the original images. You can either just keep the original image in memory with the scaled one used for display, or you can just store a file name and load the image again when printing.

Comment: Note that for resizing purposes, you can either create a new copy of the bitmap, or use `TransformedBitmap` as suggested by commenter Peter Ritchie. I don't know for sure, but I assume `TransformedBitmap` will cache the transformed image to ensure good run-time performance. But presumably you can then just use the UI layout as-is for printing, and WPF will automatically take advantage of the full resolution in the original image. That would be consistent with WPF's general philosophy of resolution-independence, so I'd be surprised if it didn't work that way.